# Consistency for iOS app with single supported language different from system language

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I have an app that should have only one supported language (Russian).
And I want it to be consistent, so all system messages (like Push Notifications alert) needs to be also in Russian, even if the system language (first preferred) is English.

In my project settings I have a single language:

[image]

And in plist I have everything set to `ru`:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>ru</string>

<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>ru</string>
</array>
```

It works for my own strings/xibs, but system messages are still in English and `Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first` also returns English.
Tried fresh install and cleaning build folder with no success.

I could use a hack with UserDefaults:
`UserDefaults.standard.set("ru", forKey: "AppleLanguages")`

But I feel like my needs are pretty standard and should not require a hack :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try to set the application language from `edit Scheme ->Run -> options -> Application language -> choose Russian`.

Below are the screenshots for your reference. [image]

[image]